# Block and Repeated Measures

Tags: anova, repeated-measures

I'm trying to understand what "blocks" mean in my application of repeated measures ANOVA. In my case, I am comparing three models through cross-validation (CV):

- My treatments would be each model because I'm using a different model on the same dataset.
- Then I was thinking my "block" would be each CV fold? But that fold would be different for each model. So I'm not sure a CV fold would be what one would consider a "block" in repeated measures?

Any advice is appreciated!